# How to trap the [x] in closing a Shell

Tags: java, swt

I have the following Shell listener code

```
private class ShellListener extends ShellAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void shellClosed( ShellEvent e )
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void shellDeactivated( ShellEvent e )
    {
    }
}
```

I need to be able to trap when the Shell loses focus, ie: the user goes to another application. The `shellDeactivated()` does that. I also need to know when I explicitly `close()` the Shell. The `shellClosed()` does that.

However when a user clicks on the [x] icon at the top/right corner of the Shell, `shellDeactivated()` fires, then `shellClosed()` fires. I need to be able to ignore the `shellDeactivated()` when the [x] is clicked.

The `ShellEvent` does not have any pertinent information, it just holds the Shell object, not which Shell control initiated the event.

Is there any way I can trap for the [x] click?

Answer (score 0):

Grumble grumble

Ok, inside `shellClosed()` I pop-up a message asking the user if they really want to quit. It seems that this is considered a lost focus event (true enough). That is what was firing the `shellDeactivated()` event.

So the `shellClosed()` fires, I show a pop-up message, which fires the `shellDeactivated()` event. And things happen out of order. A simple flag and back to normal :-)